# I have to select text and get selection text from textInput and apply style on text for web, ios and android. how to do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a custom text-editor using textInput and custom **bold**, **italic** and **underline** button in tool-bar. I got selection text for web and range of the text for android & ios. Now I don't know how to apply style on selected using **bold**, **italic** and **underline** buttons. So how can I apply?

```
const [newSelection, setNewSelection] = useState({
    start: text?.length || 0,
    end: text?.length || 0,
  });

 const onBold = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "web") {
      const selection = window.getSelection();
       if (selection) {
         const selectedText = selection.toString();
         if (selectedText) {
           alert(selectedText);
         }
       }
    } else {
      alert(newSelection);
    }

 <TextInput
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          style={[S.textInputStyle, textInputStyle]}
          ref={textInput}
          multiline
          onSelectionChange={(e) => {
            setSelection(e.nativeEvent.selection);
            if (setCursorPosition) setCursorPosition(e.nativeEvent.selection);
            const selection = e.nativeEvent.selection;
            setNewSelection([selection.start, selection.end]);
          }}
          selectTextOnFocus
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          onFocus={() => {
            setFocused(true);
          }}
          {...props}
        >
          {highlightedText}
        </TextInput>
```